# Swift Transparent UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I've to make my navigation bar transparent, I tried with this code :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

But my navigation bar become white, I don't understand the reason!
Can someone help to solve this problem?

Comment: i'm using a scrollview

Comment: and i need this trasparency only in this ViewController

Comment: What frame of scrollview? Try change color of scrollview to .clear.

Comment: i changed the background color to clear ant the navigation bar still white.

Comment: @Leonardo It's clear color. Your background color is white. And therefore you can't see any changes. Change your background color and you'll see the result

Comment: no also if a scroll down, when navigation bar is over a colorful element the navigation is still white, so the problem is not the color of background of the view/scrollView

Comment: if the navigationbar would be trasparent i should be able to see what there is below it... sorry for my english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right way to make transparent `UINavigationBar` but seem like you have a wrong constraint. Make sure you top constraint of your `scrollView` is equal to `Superview.Top`.

[image]

If your top constraint of your `scrollView` is equal to `Safe Area.Top`, of course your `ScrollView` won't scroll below `UINavigationBar`.

[image]

Comment: Ok i found the solution, you helped me so much :
i've corrected the constraints how you indicated me then i checked the three checkbox : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyKl1.png